# After removing python3.5 from dual boot Ubuntu 16.04.03 (Along with W10), not able to access ubuntu now

Tags: dual-boot, unity, python, python3

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I've setup my machine with Windows 10 + Ubuntu 16.04. It was running quite well since last 17 days (since installation), but couple of minutes back I tried to remove python 3.5.2 (because it was showing 3 different version of python in my laptop 2.7, 3.5 & 3.6), I'm not able to do anything on Ubuntu now.

No Dash, No unity, not even ctrl+alt+T to open terminal. It just do nothing.

I've saved logs after removing python3.5 and reboot my laptop. but now I realized I'm messed up everything.

Can you please help me ?? There is no data in Ubuntu Machine, if it can be re-install (Freshly) that will be very help, because I want to run GNS3 & python in ubuntu.

Thanks in Advance.

From
New User (17 days of experience)

**Here is the shameful thing, which I did.**

> gaurav@gs:~$  gaurav@gs:~$  gaurav@gs:~$ echo $PATH
>   /home/gaurav/bin:/home/gaurav/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>   gaurav@gs:~$ which python /usr/bin/python
>   gaurav@gs:~$ python --version Python 2.7.12 gaurav@gs:~$ python3.6
>   --version Python 3.6.3 gaurav@gs:~$  gaurav@gs:~$ python3 --version Python 3.5.2 gaurav@gs:~$ sudo apt-get remove python3.5.2 [sudo]
>   password for gaurav:  Reading package lists... Done Building
>   dependency tree        Reading state information... Done E: Unable to
>   locate package python3.5.2 E: Couldn't find any package by glob
>   'python3.5.2' E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.5.2'
>   gaurav@gs:~$ sudo apt-get remove python3.5 Reading package lists...
>   Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done
>   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
>   required:   augeas-lenses bridge-utils cabextract cgmanager
>   cpu-checker cpulimit dynamips ebtables   geoip-database-extra
>   ipxe-qemu javascript-common libaio1 libappindicator1 libaugeas0
>   libblas-common libblas3 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common
>   libbonoboui2-common libboost-random1.58.0   libc-ares2
>   libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl
>   libcommon-sense-perl   libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl
>   libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libdata-random-perl
>   libextutils-depends-perl libextutils-pkgconfig-perl libfdt1
>   libfile-which-perl libgd-perl   libgfortran3 libglade2-0
>   libgnome2-canvas-perl libgnome2-gconf-perl libgnome2-wnck-perl
>   libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-common
>   libgoo-canvas-perl   libgoocanvas-common libgoocanvas3
>   libgtk2-appindicator-perl libgtk2-imageview-perl   libgtk2-unique-perl
>   libgtkimageview0 libhttp-server-simple-perl libimage-magick-perl
>   libimage-magick-q16-perl libindicator7 libiscsi2 libjs-openlayers
>   libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl   liblapack3 libmouse-perl libmspack0
>   libnet-dropbox-api-perl libnet-oauth-perl libnetcf1   libnghttp2-14
>   libnl-route-3-200 liborbit-2-0 libpath-class-perl
>   libproc-processtable-perl   libproc-simple-perl libqgsttools-p1
>   libqt5clucene5 libqt5designer5 libqt5help5   libqt5multimedia5-plugins
>   libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5websockets5 librados2 librbd1
>   libsmi2ldbl libsnapd-glib1 libsort-naturally-perl libspice-server1
>   libtypes-serialiser-perl   libunique-1.0-0 libvirt-bin libvirt0
>   libvncserver1 libwireshark-data libwireshark8 libwiretap6
>   libwnck-common libwnck22 libwscodecs1 libwsutil7 libwww-mechanize-perl
>   libxen-4.6 libxenstore3.0   libxml2-utils msr-tools mypaint-data
>   notepadqq-common perlmagick qemu-block-extra qemu-kvm
>   qemu-system-arm qemu-system-common qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils seabios
>   snapd-login-service   ubridge vpcs wireshark wireshark-common
>   wireshark-qt x11vnc x11vnc-data Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove
>   them. The following additional packages will be installed:
>   libboost-log1.58.0 libboost-regex1.58.0 libclick-0.4-0 libcontent-hub0
>   libgflags2v5   libgoogle-glog0v5 liblibertine1 liblttng-ust-ctl2
>   liblttng-ust0 libubuntu-app-launch2
>   libubuntu-download-manager-client1 libubuntu-download-manager-common1
>   libudm-common1 liburcu4   python python2.7
>   qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 Suggested packages:   content-hub
>   python-doc python-tk python2.7-doc The following packages will be
>   REMOVED:   aisleriot apparmor apport apport-gtk aptdaemon apturl
>   apturl-common checkbox-converged   checkbox-gui command-not-found
>   compiz compiz-gnome dh-python firefox foomatic-db-compressed-ppds
>   gconf2 gedit gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gnome-menus gnome-orca gnome-software
>   gnome-terminal gns3-gui   gns3-server google-chrome-stable hplip
>   hplip-data ibus ibus-table indicator-bluetooth
>   language-selector-common language-selector-gnome libbonoboui2-0
>   libgnome-2-0 libgnome2-0   libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common
>   libgnome2-perl libgnome2-vfs-perl libgnomeui-0 libgnomevfs2-0
>   libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libpurple-bin
>   linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1008   linux-tools-4.10.0-1008-gcp
>   linux-tools-common linux-tools-gcp lsb-release nautilus-share
>   onboard onboard-data openprinting-ppds plainbox-provider-checkbox
>   plainbox-provider-resource-generic plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
>   printer-driver-foo2zjs   printer-driver-foo2zjs-common
>   printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch
>   printer-driver-pxljr pyotherside python3 python3-apport python3-apt
>   python3-aptdaemon   python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
>   python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-blinker python3-brlapi
>   python3-bs4 python3-cairo python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet
>   python3-checkbox-support   python3-commandnotfound
>   python3-cryptography python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-dbus
>   python3-debian python3-defer python3-distupgrade python3-feedparser
>   python3-gdbm python3-gi   python3-gi-cairo python3-guacamole
>   python3-html5lib python3-httplib2 python3-idna python3-jinja2
>   python3-jwt python3-louis python3-lxml python3-mako python3-markupsafe
>   python3-oauthlib   python3-padme python3-pexpect python3-pil
>   python3-pkg-resources python3-plainbox   python3-problem-report
>   python3-ptyprocess python3-pyasn1 python3-pyatspi python3-pycurl
>   python3-pyparsing python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg
>   python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets python3-renderpm   python3-reportlab
>   python3-reportlab-accel python3-requests python3-sip python3-six
>   python3-software-properties python3-speechd python3-systemd
>   python3-uno python3-update-manager   python3-urllib3 python3-xdg
>   python3-xkit python3-xlsxwriter python3.5
>   qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
>   rhythmbox-plugins   sessioninstaller shutter snapd
>   software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
>   system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome
>   system-config-printer-udev   totem-plugins ttf-mscorefonts-installer
>   ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-desktop   ubuntu-drivers-common
>   ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
>   ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk   ubuntu-software ubuntu-standard
>   ubuntu-system-service ufw unattended-upgrades unity
>   unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-lens-photos
>   unity-scope-calculator   unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks
>   unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp
>   unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-home
>   unity-scope-manpages   unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc
>   unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-virtualbox   unity-scope-yelp
>   unity-scope-zotero update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier 
>   update-notifier-common usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk xdiagnose
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:   libboost-log1.58.0
>   libboost-regex1.58.0 libclick-0.4-0 libcontent-hub0 libgflags2v5
>   libgoogle-glog0v5 liblibertine1 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0
>   libubuntu-app-launch2   libubuntu-download-manager-client1
>   libubuntu-download-manager-common1 libudm-common1 liburcu4   python
>   python2.7 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 0 upgraded, 17 newly
>   installed, 178 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 1,876 kB of
>   archives. After this operation, 655 MB disk space will be freed. Do
>   you want to continue? [Y/n]  Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   xenial-updates/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1 [224
>   kB] Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python
>   amd64 2.7.11-1 [137 kB] Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   xenial-updates/main amd64 libboost-regex1.58.0 amd64
>   1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 [261 kB] Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64
>   libboost-log1.58.0 amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 [422 kB] Get:5
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64
>   libclick-0.4-0 amd64 0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1 [58.3 kB] Get:6
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64
>   liblibertine1 amd64 1.0.0+16.04.20160411-0ubuntu1 [47.9 kB] Get:7
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 liburcu4
>   amd64 0.9.1-3 [47.3 kB] Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   xenial/universe amd64 liblttng-ust-ctl2 amd64 2.7.1-1 [72.2 kB] Get:9
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64
>   liblttng-ust0 amd64 2.7.1-1 [127 kB] Get:10
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64
>   libubuntu-app-launch2 amd64 0.5+15.10.20150817-0ubuntu3 [43.6 kB]
>   Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64
>   libgflags2v5 amd64 2.1.2-3 [54.4 kB] Get:12
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64
>   libgoogle-glog0v5 amd64 0.3.4-0.1 [49.3 kB] Get:13
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64
>   libudm-common1 amd64 1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1 [24.5 kB] Get:14
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64
>   libubuntu-download-manager-common1 amd64 1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1
>   [9,962 B] Get:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe
>   amd64 libubuntu-download-manager-client1 amd64
>   1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1 [109 kB] Get:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64
>   libcontent-hub0 amd64 0.1+16.04.20160309-0ubuntu1 [124 kB] Get:17
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64
>   qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 amd64 0.1+16.04.20160309-0ubuntu1 [64.7
>   kB] Fetched 1,876 kB in 4s (399 kB/s)
>   (Reading database ... 204708 files and directories currently
>   installed.) Removing aisleriot (1:3.18.2-1ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   ubuntu-core-launcher (2.28.5) ... Removing apport-gtk
>   (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.12) ... Removing apport (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.12) ...
>   Removing ubuntu-desktop (1.361.1) ... Removing language-selector-gnome
>   (0.165.4) ... Removing ubuntu-software (3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.6) ...
>   Removing gnome-software (3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.6) ... Removing
>   nautilus-share (0.7.3-2ubuntu1) ... Removing apturl (0.5.2ubuntu11.1)
>   ... Removing apturl-common (0.5.2ubuntu11.1) ... Removing checkbox-gui
>   (1.2.4-0ubuntu1) ... Removing checkbox-converged (1.2.4-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Removing command-not-found (0.3ubuntu16.04.2) ... Removing unity
>   (7.4.0+16.04.20160906-0ubuntu1) ... Removing compiz
>   (1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-0ubuntu1) ... Removing compiz-gnome
>   (1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-0ubuntu1) ... Removing python3-uno
>   (1:5.4.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1) ... Removing google-chrome-stable
>   (62.0.3202.94-1) ... update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to
>   provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
>   update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide
>   /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode Removing
>   unattended-upgrades (0.90ubuntu0.8) ... Removing sessioninstaller
>   (0.20+bzr150-0ubuntu4.1) ... Removing python3-commandnotfound
>   (0.3ubuntu16.04.2) ... Removing python3-gdbm:amd64
>   (3.6.3-0ubuntu1~16.04.york0) ... Removing xdiagnose (3.8.4.1) ...
>   Removing firefox (57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.5) ... Removing
>   foomatic-db-compressed-ppds (20160212-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   libgnomevfs2-extra:amd64 (1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1) ... Removing shutter
>   (0.93.1-1ubuntu1) ... Removing libgnome2-perl (1.046-2build1) ...
>   Removing libgnome2-vfs-perl (1.082-1build2) ... Removing
>   libgnomeui-0:amd64 (2.24.5-3.1) ... Removing libbonoboui2-0:amd64
>   (2.24.5-3ubuntu1) ... Removing libgnome2-0:amd64 (2.32.1-5ubuntu1) ...
>   Removing gedit (3.18.3-0ubuntu4) ... Removing
>   unity-control-center-signon (0.1.8+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Removing ibus-table (1.9.1-3ubuntu2) ... Removing gnome-orca
>   (3.18.2-1ubuntu3) ... Removing gnome-terminal (3.18.3-1ubuntu1) ...
>   update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/lxterm to provide
>   /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator (x-terminal-emulator) in auto mode
>   Removing gns3-gui (2.1.0~xenial1) ... Removing gns3-server
>   (2.1.0~xenial1) ... Removing printer-driver-postscript-hp
>   (3.16.3+repack0-1) ... Removing hplip (3.16.3+repack0-1) ... Removing
>   hplip-data (3.16.3+repack0-1) ... dpkg: warning: while removing
>   hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/fax' not empty so not removed
>   dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data, directory
>   '/usr/share/hplip/pcard' not empty so not removed dpkg: warning: while
>   removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/base/pexpect' not
>   empty so not removed dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data,
>   directory '/usr/share/hplip/installer' not empty so not removed dpkg:
>   warning: while removing hplip-data, directory
>   '/usr/share/hplip/copier' not empty so not removed dpkg: warning:
>   while removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/scan' not empty
>   so not removed dpkg: warning: while removing hplip-data, directory
>   '/usr/share/hplip/prnt' not empty so not removed dpkg: warning: while
>   removing hplip-data, directory '/usr/share/hplip/ui4' not empty so not
>   removed Removing ubuntu-standard (1.361.1) ... Removing
>   language-selector-common (0.165.4) ... Removing libgnome2-bin
>   (2.32.1-5ubuntu1) ... Removing libpurple-bin (1:2.10.12-0ubuntu5.2)
>   ... Removing linux-tools-gcp (4.10.0.1008.10) ... Removing
>   linux-tools-4.10.0-1008-gcp (4.10.0-1008.8) ... Removing
>   linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1008 (4.10.0-1008.8) ... Removing
>   linux-tools-common (4.4.0-98.121) ... Removing onboard-data
>   (1.2.0-0ubuntu5) ... Removing onboard (1.2.0-0ubuntu5) ... Removing
>   openprinting-ppds (20160212-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   plainbox-provider-checkbox (0.25-1) ... Removing
>   plainbox-provider-resource-generic (0.23-1) ... Removing
>   plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.2) ... update-initramfs:
>   deferring update (trigger activated) Removing printer-driver-foo2zjs
>   (20151024dfsg0-1ubuntu1) ... Removing printer-driver-foo2zjs-common
>   (20151024dfsg0-1ubuntu1) ... Removing printer-driver-ptouch (1.4-1)
>   ... Removing printer-driver-pxljr (1.4+repack0-4) ... Removing
>   pyotherside (1.4.0-2) ... Removing python3-apport (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.12)
>   ... Removing system-config-printer-gnome (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2) ...
>   Removing python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14) ...
>   Removing software-properties-gtk (0.96.20.7) ... Removing
>   unity-lens-photos (1.0+14.04.20140318-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   python3-oauthlib (1.0.3-1) ... Removing python3-blinker
>   (1.3.dfsg2-1build1) ... Removing python3-brlapi (5.3.1-2ubuntu2.1) ...
>   Removing python3-bs4 (4.4.1-1) ... Removing python3-gi-cairo
>   (3.20.0-0ubuntu1) ... Removing python3-cairo (1.10.0+dfsg-5build1) ...
>   Removing python3-cryptography (1.2.3-1ubuntu0.1) ... Removing
>   python3-cffi-backend (1.5.2-1ubuntu1) ... Removing python3-plainbox
>   (0.25-1) ... Removing system-config-printer-common
>   (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2) ... Removing usb-creator-gtk (0.3.2) ...
>   Removing usb-creator-common (0.3.2) ... Removing
>   python3-checkbox-support (0.22-1) ... Removing
>   system-config-printer-udev (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2) ... Removing
>   python3-cups (1.9.73-0ubuntu2) ... Removing ttf-mscorefonts-installer
>   (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ... Removing software-properties-common (0.96.20.7)
>   ... Removing unity-scope-openclipart (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Removing python3-feedparser (5.1.3-3build1) ... Removing
>   python3-pyatspi (2.18.0+dfsg-3) ... Removing python3-guacamole
>   (0.9.2-1) ... Removing python3-html5lib (0.999-4) ... Removing
>   python3-httplib2 (0.9.1+dfsg-1) ... Removing python3-idna (2.0-3) ...
>   Removing python3-jinja2 (2.8-1) ... Removing python3-jwt
>   (1.3.0-1ubuntu0.1) ... Removing python3-louis (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.1) ...
>   Removing unity-scope-devhelp (0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Removing python3-lxml (3.5.0-1build1) ... Removing rhythmbox-plugins
>   (3.3-1ubuntu7) ... Removing python3-mako (1.0.3+ds1-1ubuntu1) ...
>   Removing python3-markupsafe (0.23-2build2) ... Removing python3-padme
>   (1.1.1-2) ... Removing python3-pexpect (4.0.1-1) ... Removing
>   python3-pil:amd64 (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ... Removing
>   python3-problem-report (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.12) ... Removing
>   python3-ptyprocess (0.5-1) ... Removing python3-pyasn1 (0.1.9-1) ...
>   Removing python3-software-properties (0.96.20.7) ... Removing
>   python3-pycurl (7.43.0-1ubuntu1) ... Removing python3-pyparsing
>   (2.0.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1) ... Removing python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets
>   (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4) ... Removing python3-pyqt5.qtsvg
>   (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4) ... Removing python3-pyqt5 (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4)
>   ... Removing python3-renderpm:amd64 (3.3.0-1) ... Removing
>   python3-reportlab (3.3.0-1) ... Removing python3-reportlab-accel:amd64
>   (3.3.0-1) ... Removing python3-sip (4.17+dfsg-1build1) ... Removing
>   python3-speechd (0.8.3-1ubuntu3) ... Removing python3-systemd
>   (231-2build1) ... Removing totem-plugins (3.18.1-1ubuntu4) ...
>   Removing python3-xdg (0.25-4) ... Removing ubuntu-drivers-common
>   (1:0.4.17.3) ... Removing python3-xkit (0.5.0ubuntu2) ... Removing
>   python3-xlsxwriter (0.7.3-1) ... Removing rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
>   (3.3-1ubuntu7) ... Removing rhythmbox (3.3-1ubuntu7) ... Removing
>   qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside:amd64 (1.4.0-2) ... Removing
>   ubuntu-minimal (1.361.1) ... Removing ubuntu-system-service (0.3) ...
>   Removing ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ... Skip stopping firewall: ufw (not
>   enabled) Removing unity-scope-calculator (0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1)
>   ... Removing unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks
>   (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ... Removing unity-scope-colourlovers
>   (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks (0.1+13.10.20130809.1-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Removing unity-scope-gdrive (0.9+16.04.20151125-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   unity-scope-home (6.8.2+16.04.20160212.1-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   unity-scope-manpages (3.0+14.04.20140324-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   unity-scope-texdoc (0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   unity-scope-tomboy (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   unity-scope-virtualbox (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   unity-scope-yelp (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   unity-scope-zotero (0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1) ... Removing snapd
>   (2.28.5) ... Warning: Stopping snapd.service, but it can still be
>   activated by:   snapd.socket Removing apparmor (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7)
>   ... Removing aptdaemon (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14) ... Removing
>   libgnome-2-0:amd64 (2.32.1-5ubuntu1) ... Removing libgnome2-common
>   (2.32.1-5ubuntu1) ... Removing python3-cupshelpers
>   (1.5.7+20160212-0ubuntu2) ... Removing python3-requests (2.9.1-3) ...
>   Removing python3-urllib3 (1.13.1-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ... Removing
>   libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 (1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1) ... Removing
>   libgnomevfs2-common (1:2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1) ... Removing gconf2
>   (3.2.6-3ubuntu6) ... Removing update-notifier (3.168.5) ... Removing
>   update-notifier-common (3.168.5) ... Removing python3-debian
>   (0.1.27ubuntu2) ... Removing python3-chardet (2.3.0-2) ... Removing
>   python3-six (1.10.0-3) ... Removing dh-python (2.20151103ubuntu1.1)
>   ... Removing unity-control-center (15.04.0+16.04.20170214-0ubuntu1)
>   ... Removing indicator-bluetooth (0.0.6+16.04.20160526-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Removing ibus (1.5.11-1ubuntu2) ... Removing gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64
>   (1.5.11-1ubuntu2) ... Removing gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
>   Removing update-manager (1:16.04.10) ... Removing
>   python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14) ... Removing
>   python3-aptdaemon (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14) ... Removing python3-defer
>   (1.0.6-2build1) ... Removing update-manager-core (1:16.04.10) ...
>   Removing python3-update-manager (1:16.04.10) ... Removing
>   python3-pkg-resources (20.7.0-1) ... Removing
>   ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:16.04.23) ... Removing python3-dbus
>   (1.2.0-3) ... Removing ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:16.04.23) ...
>   Removing python3-distupgrade (1:16.04.23) ... Removing python3-gi
>   (3.20.0-0ubuntu1) ... Removing lsb-release (9.20160110ubuntu0.2) ...
>   Removing python3-apt (1.1.0~beta1build1) ... dpkg: python3: dependency
>   problems, but removing anyway as you requested:  python-apt-common
>   depends on python | python3; however:   Package python is not
>   installed.   Package python3 is to be removed.
>
> Removing python3 (3.5.1-3) ... Removing python3.5
>   (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3) ... Processing triggers for
>   desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ... Processing triggers for
>   bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ... Rebuilding
>   /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index... Processing triggers for
>   mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for
>   libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for
>   man-db (2.7.5-1) ... Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme
>   (0.15-0ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for cups (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3)
>   ... Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ... Processing
>   triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ... Processing triggers
>   for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ... Processing triggers for
>   initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.9) ... update-initramfs: Generating
>   /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-38-generic Processing triggers for doc-base
>   (0.10.7) ... Processing 2 removed doc-base files... Selecting
>   previously unselected package python2.7. (Reading database ... 190546
>   files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
>   .../python2.7_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
>   python2.7 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1) ... Selecting previously
>   unselected package python. Preparing to unpack
>   .../python_2.7.11-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking python (2.7.11-1) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package libboost-regex1.58.0:amd64.
>   Preparing to unpack
>   .../libboost-regex1.58.0_1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking libboost-regex1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package libboost-log1.58.0. Preparing
>   to unpack .../libboost-log1.58.0_1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking libboost-log1.58.0 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) ... Selecting
>   previously unselected package libclick-0.4-0:amd64. Preparing to
>   unpack .../libclick-0.4-0_0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking libclick-0.4-0:amd64 (0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package liblibertine1:amd64. Preparing
>   to unpack .../liblibertine1_1.0.0+16.04.20160411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
>   ... Unpacking liblibertine1:amd64 (1.0.0+16.04.20160411-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package liburcu4:amd64. Preparing to
>   unpack .../liburcu4_0.9.1-3_amd64.deb ... Unpacking liburcu4:amd64
>   (0.9.1-3) ... Selecting previously unselected package
>   liblttng-ust-ctl2:amd64. Preparing to unpack
>   .../liblttng-ust-ctl2_2.7.1-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
>   liblttng-ust-ctl2:amd64 (2.7.1-1) ... Selecting previously unselected
>   package liblttng-ust0:amd64. Preparing to unpack
>   .../liblttng-ust0_2.7.1-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking liblttng-ust0:amd64
>   (2.7.1-1) ... Selecting previously unselected package
>   libubuntu-app-launch2:amd64. Preparing to unpack
>   .../libubuntu-app-launch2_0.5+15.10.20150817-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking libubuntu-app-launch2:amd64 (0.5+15.10.20150817-0ubuntu3)
>   ... Selecting previously unselected package libgflags2v5. Preparing to
>   unpack .../libgflags2v5_2.1.2-3_amd64.deb ... Unpacking libgflags2v5
>   (2.1.2-3) ... Selecting previously unselected package
>   libgoogle-glog0v5. Preparing to unpack
>   .../libgoogle-glog0v5_0.3.4-0.1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
>   libgoogle-glog0v5 (0.3.4-0.1) ... Selecting previously unselected
>   package libudm-common1. Preparing to unpack
>   .../libudm-common1_1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
>   libudm-common1 (1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ... Selecting previously
>   unselected package libubuntu-download-manager-common1. Preparing to
>   unpack
>   .../libubuntu-download-manager-common1_1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
>   ... Unpacking libubuntu-download-manager-common1
>   (1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ... Selecting previously unselected
>   package libubuntu-download-manager-client1. Preparing to unpack
>   .../libubuntu-download-manager-client1_1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
>   ... Unpacking libubuntu-download-manager-client1
>   (1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ... Selecting previously unselected
>   package libcontent-hub0:amd64. Preparing to unpack
>   .../libcontent-hub0_0.1+16.04.20160309-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking libcontent-hub0:amd64 (0.1+16.04.20160309-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package
>   qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1. Preparing to unpack
>   .../qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1_0.1+16.04.20160309-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
>   ... Unpacking qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1
>   (0.1+16.04.20160309-0ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for
>   desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ... Processing triggers for
>   bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ... Rebuilding
>   /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index... Processing triggers for
>   mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for man-db
>   (2.7.5-1) ... Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ... Processing
>   1 added doc-base file... Processing triggers for libc-bin
>   (2.23-0ubuntu9) ... Setting up python2.7 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
>   Setting up python (2.7.11-1) ... Setting up libboost-regex1.58.0:amd64
>   (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) ... Setting up libboost-log1.58.0
>   (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) ... Setting up libclick-0.4-0:amd64
>   (0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1) ... Setting up liblibertine1:amd64
>   (1.0.0+16.04.20160411-0ubuntu1) ... Setting up liburcu4:amd64
>   (0.9.1-3) ... Setting up liblttng-ust-ctl2:amd64 (2.7.1-1) ... Setting
>   up liblttng-ust0:amd64 (2.7.1-1) ... Setting up
>   libubuntu-app-launch2:amd64 (0.5+15.10.20150817-0ubuntu3) ... Setting
>   up libgflags2v5 (2.1.2-3) ... Setting up libgoogle-glog0v5 (0.3.4-0.1)
>   ... Setting up libudm-common1 (1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Setting up libubuntu-download-manager-common1
>   (1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ... Setting up
>   libubuntu-download-manager-client1 (1.2+16.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Setting up libcontent-hub0:amd64 (0.1+16.04.20160309-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Setting up qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1
>   (0.1+16.04.20160309-0ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for libc-bin
>   (2.23-0ubuntu9) ... gaurav@gs:~$

Comment: Only use Something Else install option. Over install without formatting to reuse same home data. "Dirty Install"
System settings or anything in / may be overwritten with defaults but any data you have added should be preserved, but good backups still important
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941872

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu *requires* Python3 for versions 16.04 and later.  A large number of the core system utility scripts operate on Python3.

By removing Python3, you've effectively disabled your system from being usable.  Python 2, Python 3.5, and Python 3.6 are all valid versions.  Python 2 and Python 3.5 are both needed by your system if they're installed.  Python 3.6 isn't part of a standard Ubuntu 16.04.03 installation so if you have it it's probably a local copy for a specific software you use or in a separate installation/usability directory.

Your only hope of respite to resolve the issue in the least-technical way possible is to reinstall Ubuntu to your computer.  And then don't fuss with the Python software that is installed on the system in the future.

Comment: I'm ready to do that. I mean reinstall Ubuntu. Could you please help me to do that. I'm on dual boot setup. So little afraid of doing that. I"ve bootable ubuntu in pendrive.